# App does not contain a definition for UiParent

Tags: xamarin

I've got an Azure AD B2C set up, and have configured external identity providers. I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/azure-ad-b2c/) and have gotten stuck right here MainActivity.cs (Android project in my Xamarin solution):

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            App.UiParent = new UIParent(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Activity);
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

**I'm getting red squiggled on App.UiParent, saying "[UiParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.uiparent?view=azure-dotnet)" is not on App.**

I've added the 1.1 release of [Microsoft Authentication Library / Microsoft.Identity.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client), and even futzed around with the dev releases and got the same result.

As a bonus, I'm also getting Forms.Context is obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the public variable in your `Application` subclass:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public static IAuthenticate AuthenticationProvider { get; private set; }

    public static UIParent UiParent = null;

    public App()
    {
      ~~~~
```

Re: [App.cs#L12](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/4c0f3732da8857bcd1773b0a69368643d9014629/WebServices/TodoAzureAuthADB2CClientFlow/TodoAzure/App.cs#L12)